# Move image from left to right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

In my application after the view load, an image should appear from left to right.
I am writing this code in in `viewdidload` or `viewwillappear`:

```
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PG05(REV).jpg"];
       UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
       for (int i=-1024; i<=0; i++) {
               NSLog(@"i: %d",i);
       sleep(5);
       imageView.frame = CGRectMake(i,0, 1024, 768);
               NSLog(@"done");
       [self.view addSubview:imageView];

       }
       [imageView release];
```

But problem is that, before loading view it executes the above code than loads the view, so that it seems that view loaded and a static image is there.
But my requirement is that first view load completely then image should display from left to right.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not call the -(void)addSubview: inside your for loop. You just need to call it once.
Secondly, if you want to animate your imageView from left to right, [UIView class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html) provides great functionalities for this using blocks.

Your code should look like this :

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PG05(REV).jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-1024, 0, 1024, 768);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release]; //Your imageView is now retained by self.view

//Animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                 animations:^(void) {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
                 }];
```

The animateWithDuration: method will handle the animation timer for you, just set the duration argument according to your needs.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. Can u plz tell me what will be the condition/code to stop this animation on touchBegan(touch the image).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function and call it using timer method.

```
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0 target:self selector:@selector(moveImage) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

-(void)moveImage
{
//Your condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for UIView animations.

Put your imageView down at -1024 left, then go:

```
[imageView animateWithDuration:5 animations:^{
    [imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 1024, 768)];
}];
```

Ta-da! A five second animation of your image sliding to the right.

Check out the animation methods of UIView (of which UIImageView is a subclass):
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html