# Move image from left to right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

This is follower question of [Move image from left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5979298/move-image-from-left-to-right)
I have used this code for moving image from left to right, and write some code in touchBegan to stop this animation when touch on this image .But its not working during animation. when the animation end then if touch on image then this touchBegan is call.

My requirement is, during animation if image is touched then touchBegan should be execute.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PG05(REV).jpg"];
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
imageView.frame = CGRectMake(-1024, 0, 1024, 768);
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
[imageView release]; //Your imageView is now retained by self.view

//Animation
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                 animations:^(void) {
                    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768);
                 }];
```

Please help me out.

Comment: then you should use the approach mentioned in the last answer of your previous question. and in touches method just invalidate the time. code will be different but this will give you control for touches event

Comment: I haven't tested this, but would it be possible to overwrite the animation to animate to the current position and stop it that way? `[UIView animateWithDuration0.01 animations:^(void) { imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, imageView.center.x, imageView.center.y); }];`

Comment: @SimonBS: but how I do as during animation touches method is not accessing. I can stop the animation or do anything but problem is that during animation if I touches the image the touches method is not called and when once the animation completed and then touch on image then its perfectly called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need this method [-animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration%3adelay%3aoptions%3aanimations%3acompletion%3a). Replace current method with

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:10.0
                      delay:0.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1024, 768); 
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

This should enable touches during the animation.

Comment: Thanks !!! its working perfectly. Can you plz tell me it there any option for continuous animation.

Comment: There are other `options` that you can provide which are mentioned [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions). For continuous animations, you could consider `UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat` and `UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse`.

Comment: Thanks it working !!! Please give me some idea regarding: Why my animation goes very slow at the end. Is there any sleep like thing ?

Comment: That is because of the implicit Animation Curve that is defined - `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut`. You can change this, again, using the `options` parameter. If you are looking for linear timing, use `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear`.